# How to solve this ODE with constraints?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$s'(x)=\frac{1}{s(x)-x}$ on $x\in [0,1]$

with restrictions that $x\leq s (x)\leq x+1$ for $x\in [0,1]$.

How to solve the equation analytically and is the solution unique? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

If you integrate for $x$, you arrive easily to $$x(s)=c_1 e^{-s}+s-1$$ If you want to express $s(x)$, this requires involving Lambert function W (search Wikipedia) and you should arrive to $$s(x)=W\left(c_1  e^{-(x+1)}\right)+x+1$$ In Wikipedia, you will find good description of the properties of Lambert function and this will allow you to finish your work.